# How to associate Models using one to one relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Given below are two models associated with one to many relationship and it works fine

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events, dependent: :destroy
end
```

but when I associate them one to one

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :event, dependent: :destroy
end
```

It gives me the following error

```
undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass
```

Events Controller

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @event = current_user.event.build
  end

def create
    @event = current_user.event.build(event_params)

    if @event.save
        redirect_to @event
    else
          render 'new'
      end
  end

private

  def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:date, :time, :venue)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is throwing the error is because there is no event for that user. While that is how to build through association for a `has_many` relationship, it doesn't work for `has_one`. See the [documentation on `has_one`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-one-association-reference) where they say that calling `.build` will not work.

Instead use `@event = current_user.create_event`

Adding a `has_one` relationship will give you the following methods:

- `association(force_reload = false)`
- `association=(associate)`
- `build_association(attributes = {})`
- `create_association(attributes = {})`
- `create_association!(attributes = {})`

Answer (score 0):

For `has_one` associations, Rails provides a special set of methods for building the association ([documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one))

- `build_event`
- `create_event`

Both of these take a hash of attributes just like the `build` method of a `has_many` association does.

In your case, change `current_user.event.build` to `current_user.build_event` and `current_user.event.build(event_params)` to `current_user.build_event(event_params)`